# org.apache.commons cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, payment-gateway

I have tried an payment gateway integration. The code given by the gate way have some error

```
 byte[] hexBytes = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex().encode(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
```

The error is

> org.apache.commons cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Have you added corresponding apache commons jar file to your classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Apache Commons  Codec in your Classpath?

If you are using maven, include it with this snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Or just drop the [.jar from here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10) into your classpath.

Comment: You are welcome. Of it helped, please mark my answer as solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error could raise wether from not importing:

```
import org.apache.commons.*;
```

Or from not declaring previously any of the variables you are using here.

Comment: He referenced the codec class with the full package name. This way, an import is irrelevant.

Comment: I have the and specified the import. But still not working